# what is the function of "&" behind the "Timekeeper"

Tags: c++

here is the code

```
TimeKeeper& operator++(){
    d_seconds++;
    return *this;
      }
```

I want to know what is the  function of   "&" behind  Timekeeper ,and if I delete it ,what is the difference.
For example:

```
TimeKeeper operator++() {
    d_seconds++;
    return *this;       }
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes the return value a reference, which is sort of like a pointer. Without the & the function returns a copy